# My available space decreases when I deleted .local folder

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage, nfs

I am using a Linux computer through ssh (I do not have root privileges). In my home directory, usually when I run `df .` I see the message below:

```
$ df .
Filesystem               Size  Used     Avail   Use%   Mounted on
nfs:/mypool/users/user1  15G   14G      1G      100%   /users/user1
```

Something strange happened. I deleted the `.local` directory in my home (`~/.local)` to gain more space but since then, whenever I run `df .`, I have:

```
$ df .
Filesystem               Size  Used     Avail   Use%   Mounted on
nfs:/mypool/users/user1  5G    5G       0       100%   /users/user1
```

When I delete more things I get even smaller `Size` like this.

```
$ df .
Filesystem               Size  Used     Avail   Use%   Mounted on
nfs:/mypool/users/user1  4G    4G       0       100%   /users/user1
```

I do not know why the available size decreases. Do you have any clue?

Comment: What is this system? How are disks set up? You show that your home directory is in the non-standard `/users` directory and it is exported over NFS so it isn't a local disk. And that your usage is always 100%. Could your sysadmin be using some sort of system that dynamically allocates space as needed so you are always given only what you use and no more?

Comment: I think you are right. Maybe I should have asked the sysadmin and not here. I asked here because I thought maybe this is a well-known issue and probably can be fixed with some commands. The system I think is Alma Linux.

Comment: OK, you might as well add that to the question, but what we really need is not the operating system but what kind of setup this is. Presumably, this isn't your laptop, it's some server that is managed by professionals, right? In order to be able to help, we would need to know exactly how the system is set up, and I doubt you can tell us (if you can, please edit it into the question). So yes, your sysadmin is probably the best person to ask.

Comment: I think it's an easy issue to diagnose and fix, but it requires local knowledge that only the admin of the NFS server has. I'm thinking there is some other user or system process that is desperately trying to grab as much disk as possible, so whenever you free space up, it immediately uses it, decreasing the overall available space for your user's mount point.  I'm closing this as "unclear", meaning we can't solve it for you without further information.